# Download zip file with Django from API request

Tags: python, django, zip

Currently, I am making a call to an API that sends back a zip file. When using `request`:

```
res = requests.get('http://url/to/api, headers={auth: 'token', Accept: 'application/octet-stream'}
```

I am able to get the binary response content using `res.content`:

Example:

```
b'PK\x05\x06\...
```

Then I return the binary response from my view to my template:

```
return render(request, 'example.html', {'zipfile': res.content}
```

At my `example.html`, I tried to create a button to download the zip file using:

```
<a href="data:application/zip, {{ zipfile }}" download>Download</a>
```

However, I got back a corrupted zip file.

I'm quite new to Django, any help here is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: why do you send it to template ? zip file is `bytes` data but sending to `string` template you create unreadable item because it has to convert `bytes` to `string`. If you want to put it `<a>` then better convert to `base64` string. similar to image in [Flask: How to use BytesIO in Flask to display matplotlib image without saving in file.](https://blog.furas.pl/python-flask-how-to-use-bytesio-in-flask-to-display-matplotlib-image-without-saving-in-file-gb.html)

Comment: Mozilla doc: [Data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) - ie. `data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ==`